# Сумма столбцов матрицы

Tags: java, матрицы

Доброго времени суток) Есть матрица 100x100 нужно просуммировать каждый столбец матрицы, поделить сумму на количество элементов в столбце, и занести числа в одномерный массив. Но у меня что-то не очень получается, не могу сообразить(

```
public class Etalon {

    public static void etalonMatrix(int [][] convertToMatrix) {

        int [][] mas = convertToMatrix;
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < convertToMatrix[0].length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < convertToMatrix.length; j++){
                s = s + mas [j][i];
                System.out.println(s + " ");
            }

            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код чет суммирует, но очень странно, неправильно)

Comment: «и занести числа в одномерную матрицу» – все-таки, наверное, не **матрицу**, а **массив**. Так вот, а где Вы этот самый массив создаете? Создаете ли?

Comment: Неужели с вами не учиться нерд у которого за пиво/шоколадку/улыбку можно получить правильное решение с объяснением?

Comment: @post_zeew да в массив), матрица создана в отдельном классе

Comment: @E_p к сожалению нету) я бы тогда так не заморачивался)

Answer (score 1):

Переменная s в цикле не обнуляется - она только накапливается. Более верно будет так:

```
public static void etalonMatrix(int [][] convertToMatrix) {

    int [][] mas = convertToMatrix;
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < convertToMatrix[0].length; i++){
        s = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < convertToMatrix.length; j++){
            s = s + mas [j][i];
            System.out.println(s + " ");
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```